# how to run ngServe from VS2019

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I started writing an Angular 7 app and I started by using the Node tools from the command line. I'm at the point where as long as I'm in the correct directory I use the NGServe command , then open a browser session and point it to my start page. All works fine, however, I'd like to be able to hit F5 in VS2019 and for it to do the same. Is there an easy way for me to set this up?

I'll be writing a second webApi project and want to streamline it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new ASP.Net Core Web Application in VS 2019 keeping Angular as Template
2. Once created, you will notice ClientApp folder is generated
3. ClientApp folder is the Angular project
4. Press F5, VS will resolve all the Packages and will open your
   Angular application in browser on some random port.
5. That's it.

Refer below screenshot of running application using VS 2019

[image: Running application using VS 2019]

Comment: So, I'm guessing if I create a new project with the Angular Template, I should be able to copy my Angluar project more or less straight into the src folder. My only concern is that I'm using Angular 7, and I know in the past going to a different version of Angular on an already established project often breaks quite badly. I don't suppose you know the version of Angular this template uses.

Comment: It uses Angular 8.3.14 version inside VS project. As far as Angular 7 is concerned, I suppose there are not much difference between Angular 7 and 8. 

So, If you copy src folder in the new project then you would have to copy the packages listing too from package.json file.

Still if you're facing errors, can you upload your code somewhere online so I can look into it whats breaking (if your code doesn't have any confidential thing).

Comment: Not got that far yet. I've just created the basic project from the template (not added anything) pressed F5 and it blew up on me. I'm just using the command line to run 'NPM Install' in the ClientApp directory. to see if I can get the basic template up

Comment: You won't need to explicitly run `npm install` inside ClientApp directory. F5 does this work itself for first time.

Comment: F5 first time caused it to crash. The NPM install in the client app worked. F5 now runs to the screen you gave above. I'll now start to copy my Angular files in and remove the defaults and see what happens. Might take a while though

Comment: Great, thanks for accepting it as answer. I am here for any issues you face while setting it up.